# Recursion, mixed arrays, Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

I have a recursive problem that is not returning as I expect and I'm not sure how to change the function.

I would like an array containing both strings and arrays that derive from a chunk of text that is separated by boundaries defined in the text. The first pass works, but the second pass doesn't seem to correctly turn strings containing the boundary keyword into arrays and have them replace themselves in the parent array.

Recursion functions:

```
def separate(text,boundary = nil)
    # returns array of strings and arrays containing all of the parts of the email
    textList = []
    if !boundary #look in the email for "boundary= X"
        text.scan(/(?<=boundary=).*/) do |bound|
            textList = recursiveSplit(text,bound)
            end
    end
    if boundary 
        textList = recursiveSplit(text,boundary)
    end
    puts textList.count
    puts '\n'
    puts textList.inspect
    return textList
end


def recursiveSplit(chunk,boundary)
    if chunk.is_a? String
        searchString = "--" + boundary
        ar = chunk.split(searchString)
        return ar
    elsif chunk.is_a? Array
        chunk do |bit|
            recursiveSplit(bit,boundary);
        end
    end
end
```

Example of text variable:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.112.170.40 with HTTP; Fri, 3 May 2013 05:08:21 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 3 May 2013 08:08:21 -0400
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CADPp44E47syuXvP1K-aemhcU7vdSijZkfKLu-74QPWs9U9551Q@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: MiB 5/3/13 7:43AM (EST)
From: Me <me@gmail.com>
To: Someone <someone@aol.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BNDRY1

--BNDRY1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=BNDRY2

--BNDRY2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

-TEXT STUFF HERE. SAYING THINGS
ABOUT CERTAIN THINGS

--BNDRY2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

HTML FORMATTED TEXT STUFF

--BNDRY2--
--BNDRY1
Content-Type: application/zip; name="Make it Brief.ipa.zip"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Make it Brief.ipa.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hg9biuno0

<<FILE DATA>>
--BNDRY1--
```

Comment: Is this a maildir, mbox or custom file?

Comment: @BjoernRennhak it's what happens when you "view original" a gmail email. It is then saved as a .txt file. I have changed some values for readability and anonymity.

Comment: The boundaries you try to extract seem to be the usual structure you find in e.g. mbox or maildir files. I am wondering if you can use a proper library instead of custom scripting this to ensure maintainability and avoiding re-inventing the wheel. Why don't you try to use e.g. https://github.com/mikel/mail on it.

Comment: @BjoernRennhak I would absolutely love to do that, unfortunately this is for a coding practical as a path to entry level employment and they specify that you are not allowed to use any email-specific libraries and, in fact, MUST re invent the wheel.

Comment: Ok, you didn't specify this previously. Why don't you attach a debugger to this e.g. with pry and just step through the program to see what you are doing wrong. Since this is for a job interview it might be a good idea to fully understand whats going on so that you can understand it.